# jQuery script is not functioning

Tags: jquery

When I try to run this jQuery script:

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function() {
$vari = $(this).val();
$(".user:contains($vari)").css("display", "block");
};
```

it doesn't function, it just appears that the script doesn't really do anything!

This is the accompanying HTML:

```
<div class="user">hello</div>
<input type="text" id="textbox">
```

Please advice about what I have to do to get this script functional. It should grab the div with the `class` user, and if the text in the textbox with the id `textbox` has a value which is also in the `user`, it should make it visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it not case-sensitive as you want, here's an [variation](http://jsfiddle.net/rg8nU/1/) to @Joseph fiddle

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function() {
var $vari = $(this).val();
var reg = new RegExp($vari, "gi");
var $div = $(".user").html();
if($div.match(reg))
    $(".user").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: haha No problem. Btw, insert '&& $vari != ""' in the if statement to prevent the display to change with any keyup with an empty input field ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate your `$vari` variable into the selector:

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function() {
    var $vari = $(this).val();
    $(".user:contains(" + $vari + ")").css("display", "block");
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rg8nU/

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. Test out the script: using the code your provided, my script still does not work.

Comment: @user40531 - It was missing the closing parentheses. Updated, with a fiddle.

Comment: You got my upvote! :) Also: by any chance, do you know how to make "contain" NOT case-sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

```
do this 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#textbox').keyup(function() {
    var $vari = $(this).val();
    $(".user:contains(" + $vari + ")").css("display", "block");
});
    });
</script>

 <div>
        <input type="text" id="textbox" />

   </div>
   <div  class="user" style="display:none">a</div>
```